# Late 70's / Early 80's Sci Fi Mystery Show

Tags: aliens, robots, story-identification

This is going to be a very vague description I am afraid.

The show in question was a whodunnit. Each episode was a murder / mystery where a very stylised alien robot killed or committed some other crime against other highly stylised alien robots. I think it was animated, but it might just have been a motion-comic type thing. There were various clues at the start of the show, I think a couple of theories about what might have happened and then the culprit was revealed. It was on late afternoons / early evening on BBC, I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Captain Zep - Space Detective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Zep), shown from 1983 to 1984.

[image: Captain Zep and his crew]

It was shown in front of an audience who also had to work out the *[whodunit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whodunit)*.

[image: Audience with 80s sci-fi clothes.]

The aliens were drawings with which the live actors interacted.

[image: Crew meeting an "alien"]

Comment: Wow. I thought I knew Hokey... but THIS is Hokey. Hello, Hokey.

Comment: @Omegacron: it was terrible at the time... Now it has worsened with age...